# Show Outlook calendar in a screen-share, but obscure private appointments

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

Scenario:

I'm in a virtual meeting with a colleague. We want to review & discuss what meetings we have in the coming week.

I go ahead and share my screen in Microsoft Teams -- showing the person my calendar in Outlook (Outlook 2016; on-prem/Microsoft Exchange).

That works, but the problem is that my colleague can see any private appointments I have in my calendar, which isn't ideal. For the appointments that I've flagged as *Private*, it would be better if Outlook could hide or obscure the titles of those appointments during the meeting.

---

Is there an option in Outlook where I can temporarily obscure the titles of private appointments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One potential **workaround** is to create a custom calendar view, with a filter applied. When you're screen-sharing, you can switch to this view. Here's what the filter would look like:

[image]

When the custom view is applied, Private items won't be shown in your calendar at all.

**'Standard' view**

[image]

**'Hidden' view**

[image]

You can add the Change View option to the Quick Bar too, by right-clicking on the views

[image]

This gives you a nice subtle option from the top bar, which is accessible from any tab on the ribbon

[image]

Comment: Good sharing! Hi @User1973 , would you mind marking the reply as an answer so that people with same issue could get references?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there an option in Outlook where I can temporarily obscure the
> titles of private appointments?

As asked, no.

You can mark appointments as private and then no one but you can see the content of the appointment.

But Outlook does not have a switch to make the Private Appointment disappear from the Outlook Calendar, at least not natively.